# I don't understand why backslash is used in extends class in php code

Tags: php, swiftmailer, backslash

class SwiftMailerTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

why coder  uses backslash in extends class in above php code

Comment: This is a `namespace` http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to let PHP know where the class exists. For example, `\app\classes\TestClass` will let it know that the class exists in `app\classes` directory/namespace. If you will not add the path, It will look for the class in the same Namespace!

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I mean namespace!

Comment: but why  backslash used in  the front  of  "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase"  look \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. this is the full code from swiftmailer is                 <?php


class SwiftMailerTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static function regExp($pattern)
    {
        if (!is_string($pattern)) {
            throw PHPUnit_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper::factory(1, 'string');
        }

        return new PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_PCREMatch($pattern);
    }


}

Comment: to let it know that the class exist at root of the application!

Comment: Thanks a lot  Adarsh Sojitra